# #InputLevel bug? Impossible to use custom combination with #InputLevel set to 1

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using the latest version of AHK (1.1.26.01) and the following script fails to send `Space` key to the active window when I release `Space` key. So `Space` key gets disabled.

```
#InputLevel 1
Space & LAlt::
    OutputDebug, %A_ThisHotkey%                
    return
Space:: 
    OutputDebug, %A_ThisHotkey%
    Send, {Space}
    return
```

Without `#InputLevel` directive it works fine. Exactly as described in AHK help file (search for "Custom combinations").

What I want is to be able to trigger hotkeys that use `Space` in another AHK script running, that's why I need #InputLevel set to 1 as it consequently sets SendLevel to 1.

If I run the script without `#InputLevel 1` I get the following in the Keyhistory after hitting `Space`. And it gets sent to the active window.

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key 
---------------------------------------------------
20  039 s   d   0.76    Space           
20  039 h   u   0.08    Space           
20  039 i   d   0.05    Space           
20  039 i   u   0.00    Space
```

But with `#InputLevel 1` I get the the following and the `Space` is not sent though hotkey is triggered (as can be seen in Lines most recently executed and in DebugView).

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key 
---------------------------------------------------
20  039 s   d   0.76    Space           
20  039 h   u   0.08    Space           
20  039 a   d   0.05    Space           
20  039 i   u   0.00    Space
```

Is it a bug or the expected behavior of InputLevel directive?

Comment: Looks like a bug, maybe with the keyboard hook. It worked for me with `SendPlay`

Comment: @Oleg, yes, SendPlay works, it sends Space to the active window. But it fails to trigger Space hotkey defined in another script. From the documentaiton: SendSpace "creates a series of events (messages) that flow directly to the active window (similar to ControlSend, but at a lower level). Consequently, SendPlay does not trigger hotkeys or hotstrings."

Comment: Possibly Related: [Hotkey to remap keys does not trigger hotstring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373221/3357935) (See explanation under SendEvent)