# Hotkey to remap keys does not trigger hotstring

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I have a hotkey and hotstring that don't seem to work together:

```
9::(

:?ob0:(::){left 1}
```

To give some context, in one part of the code I remapped all the symbols to the number below them and vice versa so `9` prints the parenthesis `(`. Later on I put a hotstring that would type a closed parenthesis after an open one and then places the cursor in between.

Seems simple enough because they both work individually but together when I press the key for `9` and press the Spacebar I only get the open parenthesis `(` as if the hotstring was ignored.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a combination of [`Send`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) and [`InputLevel`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm).

```
#InputLevel 1
9::SendEvent (
#InputLevel 0

;; Add closing parenthesis
:?ob0:(::){left 1}
```

---

#### Explanation

- **[#InputLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm)**

  - By default, [hook](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm) hotkeys and hotstrings ignore keyboard and mouse events generated by any AutoHotkey script. This behavior can be overridden using [SendLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendLevel.htm) or [#InputLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm)
  - By setting the `9` hotkey to a higher InputLevel, it is able to the activate other hotstrings.
- [**SendEvent**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

  - Bizarrely, [remapping](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) a numkey to its <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> equivalent produced no input when `#InputLevel 1` was active.

    - i.e. Couldn't use `1::!`, `2::@`, `3::#`, ..., `8::*`, `9::(`, etc.
    - **A [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command was used to workaround this remapping limitation**
  - By default, [`Send`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) and `SendEvent` are synonymous with each other.

#### Notes

- [SendPlay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendPlayDetail) is not affected by [InputLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm).
- [Remarks for Remapping Keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remarks) may explain why `9::(` wouldn't trigger other hotkeys.

  - "*Although a remapped key can trigger normal hotkeys, by default it cannot trigger mouse hotkeys or hook hotkeys.*"

#### Related

[#InputLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm), [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm), [Remapping (Remarks)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remarks)